# Prove $\frac{d}{dx} e^x = e^x$ using $\frac{d}{dx} a^x = xa^{x-1}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

The hint in the textbook says,

> You can determine $\frac{d}{dx} e^x = e^x$ by first determining that $\frac{d}{dx}$ ln $x = \frac{1}{x}$ using inverse functions. Then consider $x^p =e^{p\ln x}$.

I understand intuitively what this means, but I'm having trouble showing it.

---

We need to prove $\frac{d}{dx} e^x = e^x$

Let $f(x)=e^x$. Equivalently, $\ln y = x$. Thus, $f^{-1}(y)=\ln y$.

Now recall that $(f^{-1})'[f(c)]=\frac{1}{f'(c)}$

Since $f^{-1}(y)=\ln y$, by the rule stated above, $$\frac{d}{dx}\ln y = \frac{1}{y'}$$

$$y'= \frac{1}{\frac{d}{dx}\ln y}$$

But $y'$  [used interchangeably with $f'(x)$] is what we're trying to show. Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: So your definition of $\exp$ is as the inverse function of $\ln$, and your definition of $\ln$ is by integrating $\frac 1x$?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not exactly even sure what the question is asking. I don't know what they're trying to establish as given and what is not given.

Comment: You mean $\frac{d}{d\color{blue}{a}}a^x=xa^{x-1}$.

Comment: No, $a$ is a constant

Comment: But $\frac {da^x}{dx}\ne xa^{x-1}$ not by a long shot.  But $\frac {dx^a}{dx} = ax^{-1}$ and if we consider $a$ as a *variable* and $x$ as a constant then as $\frac {da^x}{da}= xa^{x-1}$.  The nice thing about Leibniz notation as we can find derivatives *with respect* to other functions. Use the chain rule on this monster and it should fall out by the hint given.

Comment: Oh... never mind. But you *must* have written the problem down wrong or your text had a *HUGE* typo.  They *must* mean $\frac {dx^a}{dx} = ax^{a-1}$ that fits in with the clue that $x^p = e^{p\ln x}$. (and therefore $px^{p-1}=\frac {dx^p}{dx}=\frac {de^{p\ln x}}{dx}=\frac {de^{p\ln x}}{dp\ln x}\frac {dp\ln x}{dx}$..... solve for $\frac {de^{p\ln x}}{dp\ln x}$

Comment: Have you posted the hint exactly? You can save a lot of trouble on these boards if you post the text "exactly"... Reason I ask is that the question seems to be asking you to find derivative of ln(x) first, using inverse functions, but without using the derivative of $e^x$ (which is to be found later). Seems strange since the point of using inverse functions seems to be to use the derivative of the inverse $e^x$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is creating confusion to you is the notation. Use the prime notation, I suggest.

Instead of using $\frac{d}{dx}(\cdot)$ in the rule, use the prime notation $(\cdot)'$ as
$$(\ln y)'=\frac{1}{y'}$$
$$\frac{1}{y}=\frac{1}{y'}$$
$$y'=y$$

---

Or if you wish to go your way, then change $\frac{d}{dx}$ to $\frac{d}{dy}$ in the last step.
$$\therefore y'=\frac{1}{\frac{d}{dy}\ln y}=y$$

*In brief*, your confusion was created due to the confusion in the variable of differentiation.

---

**Edit**

We wish to prove that
$$\frac{de^x}{dx}=e^x$$

We shall use the fact that $\frac{dx^p}{dx}=px^{p-1}$ and $x^p=e^{p\ln x}$.

To clear things a bit, we let $u=p\ln x$. So, $x^p=e^u$. By Chain Rule,
$$\frac{de^u}{dx}=\frac{de^u}{du}\cdot\frac{du}{dx}$$
$$\frac{dx^p}{dx}=\frac{de^u}{du}\cdot\frac px$$
Use the Power Rule.
$$px^{p-1}=\frac{de^u}{du}\cdot\frac px$$
$$x^p=\frac{de^u}{du}$$
$$\frac{de^u}{du}=e^u$$
as desired.

Hope it helps. Ask if anything is not clear :)

Comment: This is very helpful. Thank you. I do have a question though. Doesn't this answer basically rely on using (ln$y$)'  $=\frac{1}{x}$ as a given though? I thought that was what we had to show first before proceeding. That's just how I interpreted the hint

Comment: Wait nevermind. I'm totally forgetting that $f^{-1}(f(x))=x.$ It all makes sense now!

Comment: @ManCheese: You are new to MathSE. I recommend you to accept any of the three answers which helped you. (Accept the one which clarified things the most.) This ensures that the question doesn't remain queued in the "Unanswered Questions" list.

Comment: All of the the three answers have proved that $\frac{d}{dx} e^x = e^x$ but I fail to see how any of them use $\frac{d}{dx} x^n = nx^{n-1}$ as the title has requested. So as far as I'm concerned, it is still unanswered

Comment: I (and possibly the others) were explaining where you went wrong in the solution you wrote. If you wished for that, you should have stated it clearly. I shall edit my answer.

Comment: The question in the description says, "Where am I going wrong here?", which was described by me (and others).

Comment: You can check now, I provided the solution (intended) using the Chain Rule and Power Rule.

Answer (score 2):

Your text had a *HUGE* typo.

It should be obvious that $\frac {da^x}{dx} \ne xa^{x-1}$ (spoiler alert: $\frac {da^x}{dx} = \ln a\cdot a^x$).

They *must* mean $\frac {dx^a}{dx} = ax^{a-1}$ that fits in with the clue that $x^p = e^{p\ln x}$.

Now just do it.

$$\frac {dx^p}{dx} = px^{p-1}$$

But by the chain rule,

$$\frac {dx^p}{dx}=\frac {de^{p\ln x}}{dx}=\frac {de^{p\ln x}}{d(p\ln x)}\frac {d(p\ln x)}{dx}=\frac {de^{p\ln x}}{d(p\ln x)}\cdot \frac px$$

$$\frac {de^{p\ln x}}{dp\ln x}p\cdot \frac 1x=  px^{p-1}$$

$$\frac {de^{p\ln x}}{d(p\ln x})p\cdot \frac 1x\cdot \frac xp = px^{p-1}\cdot \frac xp$$

$$\frac {de^{p\ln x}}{d(p\ln x)}= x^p$$

But $x^p = e^{p\ln x}$  so

$$\frac {de^{p\ln x}}{d(p\ln x)}= e^{p\ln x}$$
and if we just swap out variables and let $u = p\ln x$ then

$$\frac {de^u}{du} = e^u$$
which proves the claim.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you wish to prove it:

$$f(x) = e^{x}$$

$$f^{-1}(x) = \ln(x)$$

$$\frac{d}{dx}f^{-1}(x) = \frac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(x))} = \frac{1}{x}$$

$$\frac{1}{f'(\ln(x))} = \frac{1}{x}$$

$$f'(\ln(x)) = x$$

Because $e^{x}$ is the only function with domain $\mathbb{R}$ satisfying this property:

$$\boxed{f'(x) = e^{x}}$$

Sidenote: Here is a proof which I like better.

$$\begin{align}\frac{d}{dx}e^{x} &= \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{e^{x + h} - e^{x}}{h}\\ &=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{e^{x}(e^{h} - 1)}{h}\\ &=e^{x}\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{e^{h} - 1}{h}\end{align}$$

This proof requires $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to-\infty}\bigg(1 + \frac{1}{n}\bigg)^{n} = e$, which is similar to the definition of $e$ but requires justification. We have:

$$\lim_{n\to-\infty}\bigg(1 + \frac{1}{n}\bigg)^{n} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\bigg(\frac{1}{1 - \frac{1}{n}}\bigg)^{n} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\bigg(\frac{n}{n-1}\bigg)^{n} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\bigg(1 + \frac{1}{n-1}\bigg)^{n}$$
$$ = \lim_{n\to\infty}\bigg(1 + \frac{1}{n-1}\bigg)\lim_{n\to\infty}\bigg(1 + \frac{1}{n-1}\bigg)^{n-1} = 1\cdot e = e$$

Then, noting that $h\to 0\Longleftrightarrow\frac{1}{h}\to\pm\infty$:

$$\begin{align}&=e^{x}\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\bigg(\big(1 + h\big)^{\frac{1}{h}}\bigg)^{h} - 1}{h}\\ &=e^{x}\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{1 + h - 1}{h}\\ &=e^{x}\lim_{h\to 0}1\\&=\boxed{e^{x}}\end{align}$$
You could make the part where the limit definition of $e$ is substituted in more rigorous by taking the one sided limits at $0$ and proving they both equal $1$.

Comment: Your proof is correct and very nicely laid out. Now, I need to use the hint in the textbook to make this applicable for the power rule, namely to prove that $(e^p)'=e^p$ for all values of $p$

Answer (score 0):

Since by the chain & power rules $\exp^\prime(p\ln x)=\frac{(x^p)^\prime}{p/x}=x^p=\exp(p\ln x)$, in general $\exp^\prime y=\exp y$; or, if we relabel variales, $\exp^\prime x=\exp x$, as required.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the question is, "Given $\frac{d}{dx}(\ln x) = \frac{1}{x}$ and the Power Rule $\frac{d}{dx}(x^p) = px^{p-1}$ ($p$ any real number), show $\frac{d}{dx}(e^x) = e^x$." As the other answers show, only the first fact is needed to derive the conclusion, but this approach might be more in the spirit of the question (if I've read it correctly).

We know that $x^p = e^{p\ln x}$. Write $\operatorname{exp}(x) = e^x$. Taking the derivative of the left-hand side gives $px^{p-1}$, while taking the derivative of the right-hand side (and using Chain Rule) gives $\operatorname{exp}'(p\ln x) \cdot \frac{p}{x}$. Thus,
$$ px^{p-1} = \operatorname{exp}'(p\ln x) \cdot \frac{p}{x}.$$
Multiplying by $x/p$ on both sides shows that $x^p = \exp'(p\ln x)$, hence
$$\operatorname{exp}(p \ln x) = e^{p \ln x} = x^p = \exp'(p\ln x).$$
From this, we may deduce that $\operatorname{exp} = \operatorname{exp}'$ since the range of the function $x \mapsto p\ln x$ is the whole real line whenever $p \neq 0$ (so just pick any $p \neq 0$).